# Back button better UX

Tags: feature-request, android-app

I really enjoy using this app, but the back button or the phone back button is broken. As in example, if I open the main menu, click on the Stack Overflow top menu select tags, click on php in example, click on any topic, click on back ... I should see the topics, but instead I see the tags.

Comment: Should I remove my comment in favor of you suggested?